# Display text for 5 seconds after destroying object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making mobile game in which I need to show text message for 5 seconds after destroying object. I tried with yield waitforseconds but doesn't work.

This is my code now:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {


        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("bomb")) {
            other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
            scoretext.SetActive (true); //this text need to be displayed for 5 seconds after destroying game object
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("__Main1");

        }
```

I hope that someone can help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Distroy() method has another version with 2 arguments:

```
Destroy(scoretext, 5f); //destroys scoretext in 5 seconds
```

Comment: No, I have the same problem. Is it affect because this line code is in OnTriggerEnter function?

Comment: It does not matter in which function you call this. The only problem could be scoretext being a child of this gameObject (or this gameObject itself). In this case your call of Destroy (this.gameObject); would destroy it. Just making sure you understand that [Destroy function destroys the game object AND all of its children](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can only yield return in coroutines.

Try

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("bomb"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);

        StartCoroutine(DeferredDestroy());
    }
}

IEnumerator DeferredDestroy()
{
    this.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);

    Destroy (this.gameObject);
    scoretext.SetActive (true);

    SceneManager.LoadScene ("__Main1");
}
```